# Internal functions in class with friends to hide public detail

Tags: c++, class, oop, friend

I'm sure there is a better way to design this:

I have a class whose main purpose in life is to look after other classes which look after smaller things. These smaller classes have a limited amount of public data, a few methods which should only be accessible from the manager class, and a group of internal functions which should only be accessible from itself.

I was going to make the manager class a friend, but this will allow the manager to see (and use) the internal functions of the smaller class, which isn't ideal.

```
class child
{
public:
  int x;
private:
  friend class manager;
  doSomething();
  internalWork();
};

class manager
{
  public:
    child c;
};

manager m;

int i = m.c.x; // OK
c.doSomething(); // From method inside 'manager': OK
c.internalWork(); // Not allowed, only 'child' can use this function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: no friends! Connect them through an interface. You'll expose only what you want (of course this may involve some re-design too)

Comment: Note that making things `private` doesn't actually hide them---the manager can see the internal functions of the child class whether you make them `private` or not..  If you want to hide something, use pimpl.  If you're just making things `private` because you've seen other people do it and they told you it's good practice, stop.  Also, if you need to make sure `manager` can't do "evil" things to `child`, maybe they shouldn't be living in the same address space?

Comment: @Adriano: And you'll add virtual dispatch overhead someplace where it isn't necessary.

Comment: @tmyklebu:  On a practical level, what do you suppose using pimpl gets you?  OK, maybe the name won't resolve anymore in a lookup, but if the name was `private` anyway, what difference does it make?

Comment: @tmyklebu:  An "interface" does not necessarily need to employ `virtual` dispatch.

Comment: @tmyklebu yes, I would pay the price of virtual dispatch overhead (in case it'll be used and it's not mandatory). First because we don't know what it's modeling (for example data may come from a database or from some user input...). Second because such **micro** optimization is almost always premature (I can't say useless because of I don't know his context) but for sure is evil to do it when talking about design. You optimize even before you have any code to profile...

Comment: @Adriano: No, it's not evil to make design decisions based on performance and code size considerations.  It's a fact of life unless you're building something where performance does not matter at all.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Private members will shadow inherited public members with the same name and ruin everything.  And you can access private members by doing a ridiculous jig with a template and a pointer-to-member.

Comment: @tmyklebu it's evil to take design decision according to micro-optimization performance considerations! Of course performance must be considered but a virtual function call (if used) is almost always a detail (much much more can be changed before you have to care about something like that).

Comment: @tmyklebu:  Seems like an overreaction to me.  Unintentional shadowing is a clear design flaw, one which should not be made, so you are protecting yourself from something you won't (shouldn't) do.  As for the ridiculous jig, I'm all for paranoid programming, but this is over the edge.  After all, I can access the pimpl details much more easily than you can access the `private`s.  If someone *really* wants to hack & misuse your design, they will.

Comment: @Adriano: Self-fulfilling prophecy.  Much more can be changed before unnecessary virtual function calls are a major performance problem if you don't pay any attention to performance during design.

Comment: @JohnDibling: The trouble is that the ridiculous template jig is something that can conceivably happen when you're writing template code that uses member pointers.  The name-shadowing thing is also something that really can happen in real development projects.  You know you're doing something dirty when you chase `x.pimpl` from outside x's class definition and its member function definitions---at least, I can't at the moment see how that could happen by accident.  (Pimpl does, of course, imply an even bigger performance penalty, but you get real hiding.  Guess I'm saying "go big or go home.")

Comment: @tmyklebu No, it means you may even have only virtual functions in all your classes and probably you don't even see any difference in 90% of programs out there. BUT you may start to make clever optimizations (optimizations as this, not performance considerations) in early design stages and you'll have a terrible poor designed application.

Comment: @tmyklebu IMO, of course!

Comment: @tmyklebu:  I don't buy in to "go big or go home."  I buy in to "make things as simple as possible, but no simpler."

Comment: @Adriano: That would have to depend on what you're working on; if the design is too big to fit into your head, the performance aspects aren't going to help.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yeah, and `private`s leave more nasty gotchas exposed.

Comment: @tmyklebu yes and I think this discussion (without more context) is really _bar-style_. Drawback of design related questions, I guess. In general I would avoid any optimization in early stages and I'd try to use all high level features language offers. Then, with a prototype, I'd profile to see if _something_ is needed but we'd better discuss this in a bar drinking a cup of wine! LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I program for a living; I work at a software company.  I have a boss who will occasionally give me a task to do.

When he gives me a task, he simply says "Go write this widget, then commit it to source control.  Then tell QA to test it."

What he *doesn't* do is tell me "Go write this widget, then commit it to source control.  Then tell QA to test it," and then come over to my desk and start writing code.  He's telling me what to do -- not doing it himself.

But that's basically what your manager class is doing when you do: `c.internalWork();` -- the manager isn't telling the child object what to do; the manager is *doing* it.

`friend`s are a code smell.  They aren't necessarily a bad thing, and they certainly have their uses -- but they are the kind of thing that should make you sit back and think, "Do we really need this here?"  In this case, the use of `friend` is a hack around a design flaw.  The design flaw is the fact that your child classes don't have a public interface through which the manager can tell them what to do.  The hack is the fact that your manager class is just throwing it's hands up and doing the work itself.

Fix your classes so that they have a proper interface, and get rid if the `friend`ship.

Comment: I don't agree. The manager does not do the work when calling `myChild.doSomething()`. If you really think, it's such bad design (you are asking him to "fix his classes"), then why don't you propose a better implementation?

Comment: @Domi:  It doesn't do the work when calling `doSomething()`, but it does when it calls `internalWork()`, which is what I'm discussing here.  As for why I don't propose a better implementation -- I did.  But just as with what I'm recommending, I didn't do the actual work for him.  I just told him what to do. :)

Comment: @Domi:  `internalWork()` is `private` -- for a reason.  `doSomething()` is public, and therefore part of the interface.  `private` things are not part of the interface, and should be used only by the class itself.  Does that help?

Comment: I mean, I don't see your solution :)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I certainly don't want 'manager' to be calling 'child.internalWork()', thats for the childs use only. The idea is that some class gives 'manager' some work to do, the manager passes that work to the child class via 'doSomething', the child class then does something via 'internalWork' and eventually some other class can do 'manager.child.x' to get that data.

Comment: @Moose:  Right, you were perfectly clear, and I agree.  My point is your child class' interfaces are insufficient.  Add more public methods to direct the children what to do (maybe that is simply call `internalWork()` or perhaps something else), and get rid of the `friend`ship relationship.

Comment: @John Dibling: Adding more public interfaces would indeed solve the friendship problem, but it would also allow someone who isn't a manager to pass work to the child, which I didn't want to allow (they should instead pass the manager to the manager). I could move the child into the private section of manager, but then I'd have to duplicate the public interface of the child in the manager. Then again, maybe they shouldn't know about the child!

Answer (score 0):

Does anything other than `manager` need to see the `child` class at all?  Why not hide `child`'s implementation completely so that it's only accessible from `manager` using the [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)?

If this is unacceptable, why did you couple `child`'s member functions to the public data at all?  Why not make it a structure with only public data members, together with a bunch of free functions for manipulating those data members?  Then you can control access to said free functions in a similar way, by only making them visible within the translation units where `manager`'s implementation lives.

Comment: By 'free functions' do you mean functions which are not part of the class, and are simply ordinary static functions so only visible within the same file? If so I don't see how that would work as they would have no access to the private class members (unless I use friend again or the pimpl idiom)

Answer (score 0):

Manager is not the Child, and not a friend of the child. He is a Manager. The Manager needs an interface from the child to be able to manage, or to be more specific to tell the Child what to do, and to learn when the job is done, but he does not need to micro manage, he has no need to see the internal data of the child. The child need to protect its internal data, but it needs the public interface to get the task from the Manager, and nobody but the Manager, and needs to be able to tell the manager when the task is done.